# Moving files to folders based on a filename

Tags: powershell, file, copy

Howdy all of you smart people!  I am a bit out of my depth and thought I would ask a question to see if someone with a higher IQ could at least point me in the right direction.

I have a share with a lot of single lvl subfolders all with similar names in format (xxxxxx_x)
Inside of each folder there are several files:

- half will start with the same prefix "xxxxxx_x" as the parent folder
- other half has another prefix of 10 digits followed by the parent folder prefix:"yyyyyyyyyy-xxxxxx_x"

I was asked to move files to a new location where I have already scripted a deployment of same folder structure but of course the new ask is for the files to be split based on the above two naming conventions.

TL;DR:
So to summarize, how can I move a batch of files from multiple subfolders to other location based on a part of the filename? (prefix)

typical example:
c:\share\123456_2\123456_2-filename.xls should go to d:\share\123456_2
while
c:\share\123456_2\1234567890-123456_2-filename.xls should go to E:\share\123456_2

I could get the files moved and folders created (if missing) using below but how do I only target files that start with the same string (0,8)?

```
dir | %{ 
    $id = $_.Name.SubString(0,8); 
    if(-not (Test-Path $id)) {mkdir $id}; 
    mv $_ "D:\share\$_";}
```

Comment: Split the path on the back slash. Next split the 4th element (sub [3]) of the array on the underline. Now check the length of the 1st element (sub [0])  of the new array to determine the destination.

Comment: according to your new edit, you only want to move the files that start with "*123456_2-filename.xls*" to *123456_2*, but **not** the other ones with the name of "*1234567890-123456_2-filename.xls*"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - apologies should have been clearer in the original description.  I am just not sure how to best target the above at only the files that I want moved in current run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way to do this is using the `-Split` operator, or method to get just the *first* part of the broken string and check to see if it contains the underscore character (`_`); since that seems to follow the naming scheme.

```
Get-ChildItem |
    ForEach-Object -Process { 
        $destination = $_.Name.Split('-')[0]
        if ($destination -match "_") {
            Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination "D:\share\$destination" -WhatIf 
        }
    }
```

Given that you're not looking to move the other files, this will only move the files that have the same beginning.

---

*Remove the `-WhatIf` safety common parameter once you've dictated the results are what you're after.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think we are one step away from getting this sorted.  Your solution copies the entire folders to the new location including the files with other names.  I would only like to copy the files that match the folder name with its first eight characters.

Comment: @LordJabol, then use the `-File` switch in `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: You are correct - I am an absolute idiot!  I have tried with -file -recurse before posting my reply BUT I have stupidly tested it on a test directory which didnt have the target subfolders created and gci created blank file without an extension.  Without thinking I assumed it was an issue with my syntax.

Comment: I am just glad I was of some help and your question was solved:)